# Upload files to web hosting for instant download (.zip, .rar)

Tags: php

I am working on a batch file, and it requires updating every so often. My plan, is to have the bat file download and then unzip a zip file from my website on a specific time schedule. The way this would occur is the zip file is uploaded to a website, and upon entering the URL, it is automatically downloaded (The file is literally hosted soley by itself). I am completely unexperienced in Web hosting etc. and need as much help as I can get for this. I have looked around, and many of the similar questions I have found have not been answered. Paying for web hosting is an option, however I was wondering if there are any free alternatives to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some free hosting providers such as [ALTERVISTA](http://en.altervista.org).

Signup, login and than upload the zip file.
Then you can just call `http://yourwebsite.altervista.org/filename.zip` and the file will be downloaded